# NSPredicate filter by more than one string

Tags: swift, nspredicate

How do you make an `NSPredicate` that filters more than one object at the same time?  The following works perfect for one object (in this case KDED) but I'm trying to get for example KDED, KDAB and KOMN at the same time, using swift2.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Airport")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "code", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "code ==%@", "KDED")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

    fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchResultController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchResultController.performFetch()
        Airports = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Airport]
    } catch {
       print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "code IN %@", ["KDED", "KDAB", "KOMN"])
```